# Mobile redirect using screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I advertise a company, basicaly I'm an affiliate. I want to redirect my mobile viewers to the mobile version of my affiliate website. I'm thinking of doing this with screen resolution. Basicaly, if the screen resolution is unde 800 x 600, chances are big the guest is using a mobile phone.

Is this a good ideea?

Here is the code:

```
if ( (screen.width < 800) && (screen.height < 600) ) { 
    window.location = 'mobilesite';
    }
```

Ty!

Comment: Nope.  iPhone 4 screen resolution is 960x640.

Comment: Apple can go pick apples while I watch them through Windows.

Comment: Just put a link to the mobile site on the full site and vice versa - let users decide which they want to use.

Comment: Ty guys for all the comments.... I chose a resolution lower than 800 pixels for redirection becouse I want less performant mobile devices to be redirected to the mobile site of my affiliate. If a mobile device has a screen resolution of 960x640 like gilly said, It's safe to let the user view my full site, and i'm confident he will browse it ok

Comment: @gilly3 comment is very misleading. Retina iPhone still report `screen.width` of 320 in javascript even though they have 640 pixels.

Comment: @gilly3, Eli and webmasters: To be mode specific. The `screen.width` is not a reliable way to determine the `device-width` due to DPR variation and browser differences/mess shown at http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html `window.innerWidth` and `document.documentElement.clientWidth` are much more reliable, **as long as** you have a meta `viewport` of `width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0` declared and set *prior* to your script declaration and/or execution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's generally much safer to check the browser's **user-agent**, as then you will know whether they are on an Android, iPhone, iPad, iPod, Nokia, ..., and you are given greater flexibility to direct the user from there.  I use the following Javascript (probably borrowed from another source):

```
 var isMobile = function() {
   console.log("Navigator: " + navigator.userAgent);
   return /(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|windows ce|palm|symbian)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
 };
```

Screen width is an available technique.  I usually see this used with **CSS Media Queries**, changing the content based on "device-width" and "device-height".  E.g.

```
 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   /* For small devices, just CSS */
 }
```

To go with the technique of screen width / height, this is from [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.width):

```
 // crude way to check that the screen is at 1024x768
 if (window.screen.width < 1000) {
   // resolution is below 10 x 7
   window.location = 'm.mysite.com'; //for example
 }
```

Here is an in-depth [list of mobile screen resolutions](http://cartoonized.net/cellphone-screen-resolution.php).

A few caveats:

1. If a user goes to *www.yoursite.com/events/15*, you are going to forward the user directly back to *m.yoursite.com*.  This can be very frustrating when trying to visit a link on a mobile device.  You should try to reconstruct the proper URL either by a Javascript library (see [Crossroads.js](http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/)) or on the server using a redirect.
2. As mobile devices get better at rendering and interaction, be aware that oftentimes users may prefer to see the original site instead of the mobile site, full stop.  Try to provide a method back to the main site.

   Hope this all helps you suss out your solution!

Comment: Tu very much for the help. I'm aware of user agents, but user agents come and go I think, not being sure I cover all of them. This is why I am enclined to use screen resolution. For example if a user has some kind of tablet with 1024x 860 resolution, than i dont care about redirecting... it just means he can experience my own site 100%

Comment: There's nothing wrong with redirecting based on screen width.  I would just be very careful about the user flow, esp. when they are coming in from a link (e.g. not to mysite.com, but to mysite.com/something/else).  Your solution should work great otherwise.  Remember that an iPhone can properly render a page that's 1024px width with proper zooming.

Comment: Note your link to mobile screen resolutions lists their actual resolution, not what they report via `window.screen.width`. Retina iPhone does "pixel doubling" so it reports 320 pixels wide even though it's actually 640.

Comment: note rather than going window.location = 'm.mysite.com' you can go window.location.hostname = 'm.mysite.com' which keeps the same page, protocol and everything

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to add a link to the "full site" in case you catch someone with a small screen.

Also check out L http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

it is a wizard to build detection for you.

Answer (score 0):

C# Code :

```
    string u = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    Regex b = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Regex v = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    if ((b.IsMatch(u) || v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4))))
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://Google.com");
    }
```

tested & it works