# What is the best way to detect mobile screen width using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile

What is the best way to check mobile screen width using JavaScript? I've tried screen.width but get mixed results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990070/mobile-redirect-using-screen-resolution

Answer (score 1):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) would be a good tool for you to use. Have a look at the [mq()](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#mq) function (media query). It uses the CSS @media tag to evaluate media types and screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Javascript mobile detection](http://www.handsetdetection.com) method at HandsetDetection.com.
Create a site profile with no redirection rules and embed the detection javascript in your page. Then you can access the HandsetDetection.width and HandsetDetection.height variables directly from javascript for screen resolution.

Hope that helps.

(Disclaimer: I work there).