# can we Redirect website according to screen compatibility

Tags: javascript

Lets say, i have two index pages. one for mobile compatible and the other for system screens.
Now do we have any JS code for this kinda redirecting according to various screen sizes?

I know we have bootstrapping for this kinda things, but still do we have any?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile redirect using screen resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990070/mobile-redirect-using-screen-resolution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to detect mobile device and redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649767/best-way-to-detect-mobile-device-and-redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below code to redirect to your web page please check it once:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 window.location.href="mobileIndex.html";
}
else{
 window.location.href="websiteIndex.html";
}
});
</script>
```